# vim ZZ lost output with autocommand

Tags: autocmd, functions, quit

I want to check file before quitinq `vim` with custom functions, everything seems fine with `QuitPre` autocommand except using `ZZ` to exit. In this case the output is missing.

Consider following function declaration and autocommand in file `function.vim`

```
au QuitPre * call CheckBeforeQuit()

function CheckBeforeQuit()
  echo 'Hello'
  echo 'World'
  call input('Press enter')
endfunction
```

And now when I open file `tmp` with this command

```
vim tmp -u NONE -c 'source function.vim'
```

and then type `:x`, the output `Hello\nWord` along with prompt message is visible. If I use `ZZ` instead, the message from `echo` is missing. According to help `ZZ` is the same as `:x`.

Of course I could remap `ZZ` to `:x` and everything is fine now. But anyway I would like to know what is causing this difference and how I could deal with that in my function.

Comment: Interesting, from the source code, we can see that it's calling directly the `:x` normal command: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9be7c04e6cd5b0facedcb56b09a5bcfc339efe03/src/normal.c#L5524 It will require more investigation because AFAIK it shouldn't remove the messages.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with differences between `ZZ` and `:x`, but rather it's a difference between how normal and ex-mode commands show output. With ex-mode (command mode), you see the whole output. With normal command, you only see the last line (unless your mapping also enters command mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thunderbeef explained in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/vim-zz-lost-output-with-autocommand#comment38716_11002) that this is caused by the difference in the way normal and command-line commands show output. With a command-line command, you see the whole output, but with a normal command, you only see the last line.

You can work around this limitation by displaying all the desired output from your call to `input()`, which [allows you to include newlines in its prompt](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#input%28%29):

```
function CheckBeforeQuit()
  call input("Hello\nWorld\nPress enter")
endfunction
```

If your `Hello` and `World` strings are not hard-coded, but are actually generated within the function, you can instead build a string to pass to `input()`:

```
function CheckBeforeQuit()
  let quit_notification = 'Hello'
  let quit_notification .= "\n" . 'World'
  let quit_notification .= "\n" . 'Press enter'

  call input(quit_notification)
endfunction
```

If your `Hello` and `World` aren't actually strings at all, but instead result from the output of other commands, then you can capture these in your message by using the [`execute() function`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29):

```
function CheckBeforeQuit()
  let quit_notification = execute('echo "Hello"')
  let quit_notification .= execute('echo "World"')
  let quit_notification .= "\n" . 'Press enter'

  call input(quit_notification)
endfunction
```

Comment: thank you Rich and @Thunderbeef for replying to question which hanged out for quite long time.